# Can't set "Always on top" for the Skype call window

Tags: 18.04, skype, window

I am using Skype version 8.34.0.78 on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Skype has a little call window that pops up as soon as you switch to another window. It is supposed to remain "Always on Top", but it doesn't.

The window doesn't have a normal window bar, so I can't right click and choose the Always on Top-option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Make a skype call / answer a call
2. Minimize skype, little call window will appear
3. select that little call window
4. press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>
5. choose Always on Top

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to automize this in order to avoid doing this every time?

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!